# "你们现在有什么活动？" The material translation of this sentence confuses me. Is the usage of 活动 colloquial in this sentence?

Tags: translation, ambiguity

"你们现在有什么活动？" The material's translation is, "What offers do you have on at the moment?" But I don't know how it means that, as I don't know of 活动 ever meaning "offers."

Any help would be amazing!

Thanks!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When 活动 is used as a noun, as here, it refers to an event or activity.

Assuming this is in the context of retail, the 活动 would probably be some kind of promotional event in which there might be an offer like a discount, buy-two-get-one-free, and so on.

Answer (score 1):

"你们现在有什么活动？" Without knowing the full context, the proper translation should be: "What activities do you have at this moment/time?" However, the nature of the activities is unspecified, it can be made a little clear if asking this way: "你们现在有什么(促銷)活动？ Then 活动 can be seen as "the activities of offering discounts", thus the translation "What offers do you have at the moment?" makes sense, but it is defective the same way as the original question (without addressing the specific event - 促銷). To be correct, it should be translated as: "What promotional offers do you have at this moment/time?", so "offers" echos "活动" exactly.